# If I get a Dota 2 beta key, will I get to keep the game after it's released?

Tags: dota-2

Since the recent christmas event, it's become [rather easy to find a Dota 2 beta key](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46072/2578), if you've got the right things to trade.  But, it's somewhat expensive, and it doesn't seem worth it to me if you don't get to keep the game afterwards.

So, has anyone been able to find anything about this?  **Does the beta key entitle you to the full game?**  Or perhaps, will the game be free-to-play?

Comment: This is speculation at this point, but a lot of people are pretty sure that DOTA-2 will be free to play, and those who have played the beta will start with something special.

Comment: I don't believe Valve has publicly announced much of anything about their intentions regarding making Dota 2 F2P.  Gabe Newell has said that he was quite happy with how TF2 turned out after the F2P transition, so it wouldn't surprise me

Comment: Also, considering how all DOTA2's competition is F2P at this point, it would be pretty stupid for them to not to.

Comment: Well I traded my Dota 2 key for $40 worth of games (two of the indie bundles in the steam christmas sale) because I'm pretty sure you won't get the full game. I'm also fairly certain it'll be free to play anyway. But I have no idea if any of this is actually true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Dota 2 will be Free 2 Play

Gabe Newell, Valve co-founder, announced in an interview published on 20 April 2012, that Dota 2 will be free to play.

> "It's going to be free-to-play -- it'll have some twists, but that's
>   the easiest way for people to think about it," Newell said.

[Source](http://www.theverge.com/gaming/2012/4/20/2961883/dota-2-will-be-free-to-play-with-a-twist)

Comment: How can they sell an early access at [this price](http://store.steampowered.com/app/570) then, while there are plenty of free Dota 2 keys everywhere (I've got 8 to give away, if anyone is interested) ?

Comment: @Anto there are cosmetics for this price.

Answer (score 2):

since there will be a ingameshop:

it is pretty safe to say it will be free2play.
[image]

[image]

there are only cosmetic items to buy right now:

http://www.cyborgmatt.com/2012/03/dota-2-item-schema-update/#couriers

furthermore there will be trial and premium accounts.
you will automatically be premium if you bought anything in the store:

http://www.cyborgmatt.com/2012/03/dota-2-item-schema-update/#trial-upgrade

Credits to Cyborgmatt.